# Beam: Metrics.counter failed to create counter

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The `beam.DoFn` is defined as below, following this [example](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#logging) with `Metrics.counter`

```py
from apache_beam.metrics import Metrics


class ParseAndFilterFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ParseAndFilterFn, self).__init__()
        self.num_parse_errors = Metrics.counter(self.__class__, 'num_parse_errors')

    def process(self, element):
        text_line = element.strip()
        data = {}
        try:
            data = json.loads(text_line.decode('utf-8'))
            yield data['id']
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Parse json exception of ParseAndFilterFn:", ex)
            self.num_parse_errors.inc()
```

When there is one error of `json.loads`, this error comes up `AttributeError: 'ParseAndFilterFn' object has no attribute 'num_parse_errors' [while running 'ParseAndFilterFn']`

What is wrong with my code or anything I am missing?

Beam version: 2.14.0

Comment: You should use   `def __init__(self):` instate of `class  def __int__(self):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do setup in DoFn is using [setup](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/058f5bc1d03e207ce5c8b9d221a231f390b088f3/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/core.py#L492).